# Crear conexion a sql server en c# con clase

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy empezando en c# ya busque en san google pero no me queda muy claro ...

quisiera crear una clase para la pura conexion al servidor sql server o si se puede por un archivo ini .. ahora si que no se cual seria mejor.

Comment: Lo mejor es colocar la conexión en en config
Las clases para acceder a las tablas, etc

Comment: Soy novato, tengo el app.config, seria llamar la clase desde este archivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede utilizar el siguiente código para crear la conexión desde una clase en su aplicación.

```
static string variableConexionBD = @"Data Source=InstanciaServidor;Initial Catalog=NameBD;User ID=UserBD; Password=PassBD";

    public SqlConnection CadenaConexion = new SqlConnection(@"" + variableConexionBD + "");

    public void conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"" + variableConexionBD + "");
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

No olvide cerrar la conexión.

```
public void desconectar()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me funciono muy bien muchas gracias!